# HashMap only stores the last value per key

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to use a `HashMap` to store multiple values per key.

I think I have figured out what is wrong with my code, but I don't know how to fix it. As I've understood, everytime the method get sent new arguments, the HashMap overwrites itself instead of adding a new value.

How can I stop it from overwriting itself, and instead add a new title.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> owner = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public void Owner (String name, String title) throws Exception{
        List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(!listTitle.contains(title)){
            listeTitle.add(title);
        }
        else if(listeTitle.contains(title)){
            System.out.println("This person allready owns this title.");
        }
        eier.put(name, listTitle);
    }
```

The method used to print the HashMap:

```
public void PrintOwner(){
    for (HashMap.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : owner.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + " owns:" + values;
    }  
}
```

Example of how I would like the console to look like after running:

> **Jon owns:**
>
> [Lord of the Rings]
>
> [Harry Potter]
>
> **Dave owns:**
>
> [The Martian]
>
> [Frozen]

But currently it only shows:

> **Jon owns:**
>
> [Harry Potter]
>
> **Dave owns:**
>
> [Frozen]

Comment: You create each time a new list with `List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();`. You need to get the existing one instead.

Answer (score 4):

Implementation should be like

```
 List titles = owner.get(name);
    if (titles == null) {
        titles = new ArrayList();
        titles.add(title);
        owner.put(name,titles);
    } else if (titles.contains(title)) {
        System.out.println("This person allready owns this title.");
    } else {
        titles.add(title);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Excatly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Or more compact:

```
public void Owner (String namn, String title) throws Exception{
     List<String> listTitle = owner.containsKey(nman) 
              ? owner.get(namn) : new ArrayList<String>();
```